# Many To One relationship in doctrine2

Tags: php, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble understanding doctrine and trying to make an entity. Would the following sql statement correspond with the following doctrine entity

```
create table comments (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    message VARCHAR,
    parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES comments(id)
 );


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="id")
 */
private $parent_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the id's and the entity definitions a bit: with your example the parent_id variable would contain the parent comment entity instead of the id (that the variable name implies). Also your association is the wrong way around - it should be ManyToOne when defining the parent entity (many child comments for one parent comment).

Basically you can follow the example case in [doctrine association mappins](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) (section One-To-Many, Self-referencing) - there is also the entity relationship defined from parent comment to the children as an arrayCollection. In case you don't need the children connection you can just remove the related variable & inversedBy definition from the parent variable annotation.

If the referenced example is not clear enough I can post full code as well (as I happen to have precisely the same already done for comment entity)

Answer (score 0):

The `parent` (which is another object than the initialized child) can have multiple 'childs', so the relationship should be a `ManyToOne` relationship.

Also take a look at the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002956/1794894