# Doctrine ORM join user group on parent row

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible to make `@ORM\OneToOne` join where parent is null?

Currently im using `@ORM\OneToMany` to get all rows and  filtering  to find only one parnent (where parent is NULL) entity

Comment: What do you mean by Parent? You used [Class table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)?

Comment: No, I'm using `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` on same table to create parent and child "rows". 

(Single entity with self pointing) 

Check answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480955/parent-child-relationship-with-a-single-entity-in-doctrine-2/24002956)  to see example of my  structure

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with the `nullable=true` annotation :

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="commentary_id", nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Commentary")
 */
private $commentary;
```

All the documentation is here : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn

Comment: ... but still cannot find in docs criteria  to join only parent row...